# JavaScript\moment.js function won't change date

Tags: 2010, javascript, moment

I have date fields that I need to run calculations on. Its a 3 step process.

1. Run date through function to compare against holiday list, if date matches a date listed in holiday list, push forward 1 day.
2. Step 1 results then get calculated for weekends, if Saturday push forward 2 days, if Sunday, push forward 1 day.
3. Final calculation pushes date field ahead 1 more day regardless.

All my code seems to work when I console it at various steps throughtout the process, however, when it attempts to update the field with the new date it doesn't change the value. It registers in version history, but the new version shows no changes to the field. Its a blank value for the entry in version history and the original date is still present in field. I'm not seeing any errors in the console. I'm flummoxed...

Curious if this has happened to any else or any idea why this might be happening.

```
// INSERT DATES
$("#insert").click(function () {
getListData("Bill").done(function(returnResult) {
    getHolidays().done(function (returnHolidays) {
        returnResult.forEach(function (item) {
            item.insert = moment(item.bill, 'MM/DD/YY').add(1, 'days').format('MM/DD/YY');
            item.key = "insert";
            delete item.bill;
            var adjustedItem = adjustResultDates(item, returnHolidays);
            console.log(adjustedItem);
            // updatePrismDates(adjustedItem);
        });
    }).fail(function () {console.log("getHolidays Failed");});  
}).fail(function() { console.log("getListData Failed");});
}); 


 // COMPARE RESULT DATES WITH HOLIDAY DATES & WEEKENDS
function adjustResultDates(result, holidays) {
var adjustedResult = Object.assign({}, result); // Clone the result object
var hasChanged = false; // Flag to check if any change was made
const weekendDays = [0, 6];
Object.keys(adjustedResult).forEach(function (key) { // Iterate through each date field in the result object
    if (key !== 'id' && moment(adjustedResult[key], 'MM/DD/YY').isValid()) {
        var originalDate = moment(adjustedResult[key], 'MM/DD/YY');
        holidays.forEach(function (holiday) { // Check if the adjusted date falls on a holiday
            if (originalDate.isSame(holiday.holidaydate, 'day') && !holiday.eom) {
                originalDate.add(1, 'days');
                hasChanged = true;
            }
        });
        if (weekendDays.includes(originalDate.day())) { // Check if the original date falls on a weekend
            if (originalDate.day() === 0) { // Sunday
                originalDate.add(1, 'days');
                hasChanged = true;
            } else if (originalDate.day() === 6) { // Saturday
                originalDate.add(2, 'days');
                hasChanged = true;
            } 
        }
        adjustedResult[key] = originalDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'); // Update the adjusted date in the result object
        adjustedResult.hasChanged = hasChanged; // Add hasChanged property 
        
        if (originalDate.format('MM/DD/YY') !== result[key]) {
            hasChanged = true; 
        }
    }
});
return adjustedResult;
```

}

```
// QUERY ALL PRISM RECORDS
function getListData(property) {
dfd = $.Deferred();
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Billing Calendar');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Counter">0</Value></Neq></Where></Query></View>');
var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(items, 'Include(ID, Title, Bill_x0020_Date, Insert_x0020_Date)'); 
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var arrayObj = [];
    var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var queryObj = {
            id: listItem.get_item("ID"),
            marketcycle: listItem.get_item('Title'),
            bill: moment(listItem.get_item('Bill_x0020_Date')).format('MM/DD/YY'),
        }
        arrayObj.push(queryObj);
    } // End while
    var propArray = [];
    if (property) {
        switch (true) {
            case property === "Insert":
                arrayObj.forEach(obj => {
                    obj.insert = moment(obj.bill).format('MM/DD/YY');
                    // obj.insert = moment(obj.bill, 'MM/DD/YYYY').add(1, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                });
                propArray = arrayObj.map(obj => ({id: obj.id, insert: obj.insert}));
                break;
        }
    }
    dfd.resolve(propArray);
}, function() {
    dfd.reject();
});
return dfd.promise();
```

}

```
// QUERY ALL HOLIDAYS
function getHolidays() {
dfd = $.Deferred();
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Holidays');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Holiday_x0020_Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>" + new Date().toISOString() + "</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>");
var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(items, 'Include(ID, Title, Holiday_x0020_Date, USPS_x0020_Holiday_x0020_Only, Day_x0020_of_x0020_Week)'); 
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var holidayDates = [];
    var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var holidays = {
            id: listItem.get_item("ID"),
            holiday: listItem.get_item("Title"),
            holidaydate: moment(listItem.get_item('Holiday_x0020_Date')).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
            usps: listItem.get_item("USPS_x0020_Holiday_x0020_Only"),
            dow: listItem.get_item("Day_x0020_of_x0020_Week")
        }
        holidayDates.push(holidays);
    } // End while
    
    dfd.resolve(holidayDates);
}, function() {
    dfd.reject();
});
return dfd.promise();
```

}

```
// UPDATE DATES AFTER HOLIDAY & WEEKEND CALCULATIONS
function updatePrismDates(input) {
// console.log(input);
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Billing Calendar");
context.load(oList);
var oListItem = oList.getItemById(input.id);
if (input.key == "insert") {
    oListItem.set_item("Insert_x0020_Date", input.insert);
}
oListItem.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(silentSuccess, failure);
```

}

Here is a warning I get though:
moment.js:283 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 01/01/2024, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
at Function.createFromInputFallback (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js:1:3276)

Comment: I don't see any code that updates SharePoint here.

Comment: It looks like you are generating the moment date from a property called `bill` on the list items you get from SharePoint, but then you _delete_ that property from the objects. If the SharePoint column you are trying to update is named `bill`, you need to leave that property intact on the object, and update it's value, instead of storing the value (and adjusted value) of `bill` in a new property called `insert`.

Comment: Yes, the bill date is the catalyst that startrs the process. After some calculations its supposed to get copied to a new field so I'm discarding what I don't need.

Comment: @Derek, code added.